# Plotly Dash: data_table background color for individual cell

Tags: python, datatable, background-color, plotly-dash

I display in a `dash_table.DataTable` a dataframe where there is a column with color names in hex format, with this code:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = dict(COLOR = ['#1f77b4', '#d62728', '#e377c2', '#17becf', '#bcbd22'],
                              VALUE = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(id = 'table',
                                            columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                                            data = df.to_dict('records'))],
                      style = dict(width = '200px'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I would like to set the background color (and maybe the font color) of each individual cell with its content, but only for that column (which is always the first column of the table) in order to get this:

[image]

To me is ok to replace the `dash_table.DataTable` with `plotly.graph_objects.Table` ([documentation](https://plotly.com/python/table/)), which maybe it is more customizable; provided that I can implement the `plotly.graph_objects.Table` in a `dash` dashboard.

Version info:

```
Python               3.7.0
dash                 1.12.0
dash-table           4.7.0
plotly               4.7.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the background color and the font color (as well as several other properties) of each individual cell using `style_data_conditional`, see https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting.

```
import dash
from dash import html,dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(COLOR=['#1f77b4', '#d62728', '#e377c2', '#17becf', '#bcbd22'],
                            VALUE=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        style_data_conditional=[{'if': {'row_index': i, 'column_id': 'COLOR'}, 'background-color': df['COLOR'].iloc[i], 'color': df['COLOR'].iloc[i]} for i in range(df.shape[0])]
    ),

], style=dict(width='100px'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: You are very close, I updated the question to be more precise: it is necessary that it is colored only the background of that column (which is always the first column) and not the rest of the table.
I think a small change to the code you added is enough